emit does not dispatch vlaue from child to parent component
vue3 with options api
as shown in the below posted code, the child component has a drop-down list as shown in the code in section child. This child component is hosted in parent-1 and parent-2, and parent-1 is hosted in parent-2 as well.
for the attribute isOrdersDropDownListDisabled, when it is set to either of true or false in parent-2 component, the drop-down list in the child gets disabled or enabled accordingly, which indicates the binding is done correctly.
But for vModelSelectedGeometryOrder, which represents 2-way binding, it does not work for both of the following scanarios:
1- when the user selects an item in the list, the log statments in the `computed` property in the child component are executed, but the watched property in `parent-2` which is `vModelSelectedGeometryOrder` does not get executed.
2- since it should be `2-way binding`, when i set the attribute `vModelSelectedGeometryOrder` in the `parent-2` component to any value, i expect that the log statments of the computed property in the child component to be executed and displays the value,
but that does not happen

am I emitting compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder wrong? why that is happening please?
child
<template>
<div id="idDivGeometriesOrderLabelContainer">
    <label id="idLabelGeometriesOrder"> {{ tempTextGeometriesOrder }} </label>
</div>
<div id="idDivDropDownListContainer">
    <select name="" id="idGeoTIFFOverlaySettingsDropDownList" 
        :value="compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder"
        @input="$emit('update:compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder', $event.target.value)"
        :disabled="isOrdersDropDownListDisabled"
        @change="onGeometryOrderSelected($event.target.value)">
        <option value="" disabled>orders</option>
        <option v-for="featureProps in featuresRecentlyRequestedProcessingProps" :key="featureProps.get('DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOJSON')">{{ featureProps.get('DIGITIZED_FEATURE_PROPERTY_GEOM_ORDER') }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import { GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants } from '../../resources/GeoTIFFOverlaySettings/GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.js';
export default {
    name: 'GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsGeomsOrderDropDownList',
    data() {
        return {
            tempTextGeometriesOrder: GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsConstants.CONST_STRING_GEOMETRIES_ORDER_LABEL.description,
        };
    },
    components: {},
    props: {
        vModelSelectedGeometryOrder: {
            // type: String,
            default: null,
        },
        isOrdersDropDownListDisabled: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: true,
        },
        featuresRecentlyRequestedProcessingProps: {
            type: Object,
            default: [],
        },
    },
    emits: {
        'update:vModelSelectedGeometryOrder': null,
    },
    computed: {
        compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder: {
            get() {
                console.log('get.compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder:', this.vModelSelectedGeometryOrder);
                return this.vModelSelectedGeometryOrder;
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log('set.compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder:', value);
                this.$emit('update:vModelSelectedGeometryOrder', value);
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        onGeometryOrderSelected(evt) {
            const msg = JSON.stringify({ msg: verboseTag + 'xcx onGeometryOrderSelected():', evt: evt });
            console.log(msg);
            this.compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder = evt;
        },
    },
};
</script>

parent-1 GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsLayoutContainer.vue:
<GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsGeomsOrderDropDownList
        v-model:vModelSelectedGeometryOrder="vModelSelectedGeometryOrder"
        v-bind:isOrdersDropDownListDisabled="isOrdersDropDownListDisabled"
        v-bind:featuresRecentlyRequestedProcessingProps="featuresRecentlyRequestedProcessingProps"
    ></GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsGeomsOrderDropDownList>
    
<script>

import GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsGeomsOrderDropDownList from './GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsGeomsOrderDropDownList.vue';

export default {
    name: 'GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsLayoutContainer',
    data() {
        return {
            
        };
    },
    components: {
        GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsGeomsOrderDropDownList,
    },
    props: {
        vModelSelectedGeometryOrder: {
            type: String,
            default: null,
        },
    },
    inject: {},
    emits: {},
    computed: {},
    watch: {
        vModelSelectedGeometryOrder(newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log('xcx vModelSelectedGeometryOrder:',newVal)
        }
    },
    methods: {},
    created() {
    },
};
</script>

parent-2:
<GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsLayoutContainer
        v-bind:isOrdersDropDownListDisabled="isOrdersDropDownListDisabled"
        v-bind:featuresRecentlyRequestedProcessingProps="featuresRecentlyRequestedProcessingProps"
        v-model:vModelSelectedGeometryOrder="vModelSelectedGeometryOrder"
></GeoTIFFOverlaySettingsLayoutContainer>

...
...
...

watch: {
    vModelSelectedGeometryOrder(newVal, oldVal) {
        let msg = JSON.stringify({msg: verboseTag + '@watch vModelSelectedGeometryOrder', newVal: newVal, oldVal: oldVal});
        console.log(msg);
    },
}


You're emitting compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder but listening to vModelSelectedGeometryOrder in the parent. Check your Vue devtools to double-check what exactly is emitted and give a read to that page again just to be sure: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html#component-v-model

@kissu would you please have a look at the computed property in the child?i think i am emitting vModelSelectedGeometryOrder!!dont I?

I believe there already was a similar problem in earlier questions. Mixing v-model and props and events makes everything messy. The purpose of a writable computed like compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder is  to be used with v-model but here you don't do that. It could help debugging because you can set a breakpoint inside a setter but if you don't do this,  it is redundant construction. Either do <select v-model="compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder"> or don't use compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder  at all, you don't really need it here.

"select" doesn't have "input" event, "update:..." is never triggered. Check the docs when you desugar v-model to props and events https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html

@EstusFlask i removed the @input in the child component. but now when i select an item from the list, the log statment in the watcher in parent-2 does not get updated or report any results. why that is happening please? is the code only need to cleared of @input??

Can't say what happens there , parent-1 doesn't show all the relevant code, I'd expect it doesn't handle vModelSelectedGeometryOrder correctly. I don't think @input makes a difference, it just makes it harder to understand what's going on. Looks like update:vModelSelectedGeometryOrder is emitted through @change  any way

@EstusFlask thanks. but if we assume that the code is correct, then when i choose item from the list in child, the watcher in parent-2 must display that selected value, right?

This totally depends on what happens in parent-1. If you receive the value in parent-1 but not parent-2, the problem can be narrowed to parent-1, which is not currently shown

@EstusFlask i posted the contents of parent-1

I also recommend removing the sugar and keeping things explicit. That way, you could also console.log along the way, with the Vue devtools you can easily track the state emitted and be sure why something is triggered or not. Sometimes it can be messy and nice to have some narrowed-down debugging.

@EstusFlask by the way, i made a test in which i selected an item from the list in child.vue and then i received that value in the watcher vModelSelectedGeometryOrder in parent-1

You don't emit update:vModelSelectedGeometryOrder in parent-1, and parent-2 receives nothing. From your usage, parent-1 needs to have the same writable computed as compPropsVModelSelectedGeometryOrder in the child. In contrast to the child, this is the good usage for this construct

@EstusFlask yes, assume that i modified parent-1 as you suggested, would you please tell me how parent-2 should look like to listen to emited event from parent-1?also i want to maintain the two way binding please

Considering that vModelSelectedGeometryOrder is in data() in parent-2, it should listen exactly as you did, this is what v-model does, no changes are necessary there
